# How to define and use a linear function

Tags: functions

I have the following equation $T = -800n + 12000$.
I know that this is a linear function and that the two points $(0, 12000)$ and $(15,0)$ lie on the line.

When I have 2 other values of n between 0 and 15, how is it possible to determine their corresponding T-values with Mathematica.

Comment: Fyi, your function is *affine* linear (strictly linear functions are required to map 0 to 0, which yours doesn't).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
t[n_] := -800 n + 12000

t[3]
t[7]
```

returns

> 9600
>   6400

This is how you define functions. Note the underscore after the parameter name ("n_"), and that you *don't* use the underscore in the parameter's references in the function definition.

*Note: I changed your `T` to `t`. All Mathematica's symbols start with an uppercase letter, and it's a good habit to start your own symbols with a lowercase letter to avoid conflicts.*

Comment: Thank You. That was simple, shall note this down.

Comment: I'm really impressed you understood what the OP was trying to do...

Comment: @sebhofer - probably because I'm a beginner myself :-)

Comment: @sebhofer haha, I knew I had to plug some value in T. But, was just making sure.

Answer (score 5):

Although an answer has been accepted already, let me give another simple approach. You don't need to define a function just to evaluate the right hand side of your equation for different n-values. Mathematica can *replace* the n with numeric values simply be using the `/.` operator. Say you want to know the t-values for n=3 and n=7, you can write

```
-800 n - 12000 /. n -> {3, 7}
(*
  Out[4]= {-14400, -17600} 
*)
```

These *rules* and *replacements* are a big thing in Mathematica and are worth a deeper look, because they work on any kind of expression. You should check `Replace`, `ReplaceAll`, `ReplaceRepeated`, `ReplaceList` and `Rule` (and `RuleDelayed`).

Comment: `With[]` is a convenient alternative to replacement rules.

Answer (score 5):

The most straightforward approach for defining a function was illustrated by stevenvh.

halirutan's approach is also useful for substituting values into a function.

A pure [function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) represents a third option.  It becomes increasingly useful in intermediate to advanced programming when you need a function "on the fly" (i.e. you probably will use it only once and you want the definition right there in the code where it's being used so that you and the kernel don't need to search for what t[n] stands for).

```
-800 # + 12000 &
```

---

For a single input:

```
-800 # + 12000 &[3]
```

> 9600

---

Use [Map](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html?q=Map&lang=en) for multiple inputs:

```
-800 # + 12000 &/@{3,7}
```

> {9600, 6400}

Comment: +1 Since I really like that you extended your answer and explained why `(#)&` may look awful at the moment to a newbie but why it becomes increasingly important later.

Comment: Thanks. I myself took a long time to appreciate the usefulness of pure functions. For a while looked like some cryptic graffiti.

Answer (score 2):

For the record... no function, whether defined by `SetDelayed` (`:=`) or `Set` (`=`) expliclty or by constructing a pure function (using `#` and `&`) is needed. To wit:

```
   -800 {3, 7} + 12000
{9600,6400}
```

Comment: To complete this answer: this works due to the `Listable` attribute of `Plus[]` and `Times[]`.